# Accessing nested object in VB.net from newtonsoft json

Tags: vb.net, json.net

First off, apologies if this has already been posted. I have spent some time researching but haven't found a solution.

My goal is to access data from various JSON responses to web requests in vb.net. I am having trouble with nested responses; an example:

```
Dim JSON as string = '{"url2": {"href": "https://example.com/test2/"}}'
```

I have the classes like so:

```
Public Class test1
    Public Class url2
        Public href As String
    End Class
End Class
```

Deserialize the JSON:

```
Dim objURL1 As test1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of test1)(JSON)
```

This seems to work correctly, however I simply do not know how to access the `href` value, which is "https://example.com/test2/" in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts: [Nesting of .Net types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbwxw0ye.aspx) and [aggregation of instances of .Net objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604031/c-sharp-code-for-association-aggregation-composition).  (Latter link is for c# but also applies to VB.NET.)

What you want is aggregation by inclusion, like so:

```
Public Class Url2
    Public Property href As String
End Class

Public Class Test1
    Public Property url2 as Url2
End Class
```

Then to access the `href` value do:

```
Dim objURL1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Test1)(JSON)
dim href = objURL1.url2.href
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kbx80G).

For more background on nested types in .Net, see [Why/when should you use nested classes in .net? Or shouldn't you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872/why-when-should-you-use-nested-classes-in-net-or-shouldnt-you).  If you're coming from Java, see also [What are the fundamental differences between Java and C# in terms of inner/local/anonymous classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686114/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-java-and-c-sharp-in-terms-of-inner) which explains that .net nested types are not the same as Java inner classes.